# Finding $f$ from $f'$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I have a function $f:(1,+\infty)\rightarrow(0,+\infty)$ that derives and for which is true that:
$x\cdot\ln(x)\cdot f'(x)=f(x)+x\cdot\ln(x)\cdot f(x)$ and $f(e)=e^e.$ I want to find $f$ so from the given equality I reach at this point:
$$x\cdot\ln(x)\cdot f'(x)=f(x)+x\cdot\ln(x)\cdot f(x)\iff\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{(\ln(x))'}{\ln(x)}\iff(\ln(f(x)))'=(\ln(\ln(x)))'$$
but how can I continue?

Comment: $$\dotsc \iff \ln(f(x))=\ln(\ln(x)) + C \iff f(x) = A\ln(x)$$

Comment: Integrate both sides. Or use the fact that if the derivative of a function is $0$ then it's constant.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{x\cdot \ln x}+1$$

Comment: @ArsenBerk Yes, one will arrive in $f(x)=e^x\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rechecked it and I think it should be
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{x\cdot \ln x}+1$$
At this point, let's say $y = f(x)$ and therefore $\frac{dy}{dx} = f'(x)$. Then we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{x\cdot \ln x}+1$$
Multiplying both sides with $dx$, we get
$$\frac{dy}{y} = \bigg(\frac{1}{x\cdot \ln x}+1\bigg)dx$$
Now we can integrate both sides to get
$$\int\frac{dy}{y} = \int\bigg(\frac{1}{x\cdot \ln x}+1\bigg)dx$$
which yields
$$\ln|y| = x+\ln(\ln(x))+C\ ,C \in \mathbb{R}$$
Since codomain of $y$ is defined on positive real numbers, we can get rid of the absolute value and
$$y = e^{x+\ln(\ln(x))+C} = e^x \cdot e^{\ln(\ln(x))} \cdot e^C = e^x \cdot \ln(x) \cdot e^C$$
Now in order to find the constant $C$, we can use the information $f(e) = e^e$. Putting $x = e$, we get
$$e^e \cdot e^C = e^e \implies C = 0$$
So finally, we have
$$f(x) = e^x \cdot \ln(x)$$